# Math-english for non-natives: What does "supported in" mean?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, terminology, harmonic-analysis

As a non-native English speaker, I am struggling with the following sentence:

> "Fix a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is supported in the unit Ball."

Does this mean $\operatorname{supp} f \subseteq B_1(0)$, $B_1(0) \subseteq \operatorname{supp} f $ or even $\operatorname{supp} f = B_1(0)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means supp $f\subseteq B_1(0)$

Answer (score 1):

It means that $\operatorname{supp} f \subseteq B_1(0)$ as you suspected.